# Google Drive API getting an exception on backkey press WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-drive-api

I am developing windows phone 8 app which upload and download file on `google drive`. I am getting issue when I press `back key` of my device.

Here is the **error**

```
An attempt was made to transition a task to a final state when it had already completed.
```

Here is **StackTrack** of this error

> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1.SetCanceled()
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.WebAuthenticationBrokerUserControl.RootPage_BackKeyPress(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Navigation.Journal.SystemKeyPressed(NavigationSystemKey systemKeyType)
>      at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnSystemKeyPressed(Int32 systemKeyType)

I searched a lot on this issue but not get any help. I found same question on stackoverflow but no answer to this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478605/google-drive-api-getting-an-exception-on-wp8

What is the issue ? why I am getting this issue ?

Comment: Same issue here. I'm working on solving it though. Will post back if/when I do.